# Azure Stack and Azure Pack support OPC UA

Tags: azure, opc-ua, azure-stack, azure-pack

Do Azure Stack and/or Azure Pack support OPC UA?

I am planning to build an on-premise cloud solution using Azure. This solutions has to receive data via OPC UA. I already found an example which shows that OPC UA can be somehow connected to Azure: https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/azure/iot-accelerators/iot-accelerators-connected-factory-gateway-deployment

However, I am wondering whether this also works for an on-premise solution, i.e. using AS or WAP.

Comment: the link that you shared is for an IOT edge gateway which is basically on premises.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Azure Stack and Azure Pack support for OPC UA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52946394/azure-stack-and-azure-pack-support-for-opc-ua)

Comment: @4c74356b41: Thank you, I deleted the second one. Something went wrong at creation of the question.

Comment: @Aravind: As far as I understand it, the gateway is connected to the Azure Cloud, but not to an on-premise cloud built with AS or WAP. Am I seeing this wrong?

Comment: From what I read in the IOT gateway documentation , there needs to be a gateway device which will talk to azure on the internet side and also the OPC publisher component talks to existing OPC servers on premises to get the telemetry data.

Comment: @Aravind: Exactly, but I cannot read from the source whether the gateway can talk to AS or WAP instead of Azure Cloud.

Comment: That part is achieved by the OPC components mentioned in the documentation. I have not personally tried it. I can only go with the documentation. Generally a gateway is a device/software that acts as a broker to bundle messages from multiple devices,sensors on prem and send it to a data ingestion service like a iothub, eventhub etc.